# Commands are running twice in Java actionperformed

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

I created an utility that will be used within the firewall zone to get Websphere MQ contents using Java with Swing, since I'm not sure where the defect lies, I've posted almost the entire code apart from the redundant part:

```
        package testbox;

        import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
        import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
        import java.awt.GridLayout;
        import java.awt.Insets;
        import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
        import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

        import javax.swing.JButton;
        import javax.swing.JFrame;
        import javax.swing.JLabel;
        import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
        import javax.swing.JPanel;
        import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
        import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
        import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
        import javax.swing.JTextArea;
        import javax.swing.JTextField;
        import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

        @SuppressWarnings("serial")
        public class MainFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener
        {   
            JLabel lblqname = new JLabel("Please enter the queue name");    
            JTextField txtqname = new JTextField(25);                       
            JLabel lblqcur = new JLabel("where curdeth greater than");      
            JTextField txtqcurdfil = new JTextField(5);                     

            JLabel lblchlname = new JLabel("Please enter the Channel name");
            JTextField txtchlname = new JTextField(30);     
            JLabel lblchs = new JLabel("where status is: ");
            JTextField txtchs = new JTextField(8);      

            public String ID;
            public String pwdValue;

            public String qname;    
            public int cdepth;

            public String chlname;
            public String chlstatus;

            public String cmdissue;

            JTextArea out = new JTextArea();

            JButton QMGR1 = new JButton("QMGR1");
            JButton QMGR2 = new JButton("QMGR2");


            public MainFrame()
            {   
                JLabel jUserName = new JLabel("ID");
                JTextField userName = new JTextField();
                JLabel jPassword = new JLabel("Password");
                JTextField password = new JPasswordField();
                Object[] ob = {jUserName, userName, jPassword, password};
                int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, ob, "Please input password for Login", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);

                if (result == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) 
                {
                    ID = userName.getText(); 
                    pwdValue = password.getText(); 

                final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Environment Choice");
                frame.setSize(500, 400);
                frame.setVisible(true);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));
                JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane(JTabbedPane.TOP);

                tabbedPane.addTab("QAQmgrList", makeQAPanel());

                frame.getContentPane().add(tabbedPane);
                }

            }

            public JPanel makeQAPanel() 
            {
                JPanel p = new JPanel();
                p.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

                GridBagConstraints gbc_QMGR1 = new GridBagConstraints();
                gbc_QMGR1.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
                gbc_QMGR1.gridx = 1;
                gbc_QMGR1.gridy = 1;
                p.add(QMGR1, gbc_QMGR1);                
                QMGR1.addActionListener(this);


                GridBagConstraints gbc_QMGR2 = new GridBagConstraints();
                gbc_QMGR2.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
                gbc_QMGR2.gridx = 1;
                gbc_QMGR2.gridy = 2;
                p.add(QMGR2, gbc_QMGR2);        
                QMGR2.addActionListener(this);


                return p;
            }

            public void createSubframe()
            {   
                final JFrame subframe = new JFrame("Object Choice");
                subframe.setSize(1000, 500);        
                subframe.getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));
                out.setText(null);      
                out.setLineWrap(true);
                out.setCaretPosition(out.getDocument().getLength());
                out.setEditable (false);
                JScrollPane jp = new  JScrollPane(out);
                jp.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
                jp.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);

                JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane(JTabbedPane.TOP);

                JPanel queue = new JPanel();

                queue.add(lblqname);
                txtqname.setText(null);
                queue.add(txtqname);        
                queue.add(lblqcur);
                txtqcurdfil.setText(null);
                queue.add(txtqcurdfil);     

                txtqname.addActionListener(this);
                txtqcurdfil.addActionListener(this);

                JPanel chl = new JPanel();

                chl.add(lblchlname);
                txtchlname.setText(null);
                chl.add(txtchlname);
                chl.add(lblchs);
                txtchs.setText(null);
                chl.add(txtchs);

                txtchlname.addActionListener(this);
                txtchs.addActionListener(this);


                tabbedPane.addTab("Queues", queue);
                tabbedPane.addTab("Channels", chl);     
                subframe.getContentPane().add(tabbedPane);
                subframe.getContentPane().add(jp);
                tabbedPane.setVisible(true);
                subframe.setVisible(true);      
            }   

            public static void main(String[] args) 
            {SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){ public void run() { @SuppressWarnings("unused") MainFrame m = new MainFrame();}});}

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
            {               
                if (e.getSource() == QMGR1|| e.getSource() == QMGR2) 
                {createSubframe();}     

                if (e.getSource() == txtqname){qname = txtqname.getText();}

                if (e.getSource() == txtqcurdfil)
                {   
                    cdepth = Integer.parseInt(txtqcurdfil.getText());       
                    cmdissue = "qn has value messages";
                    cmdissue = cmdissue.replace("qn", ""+qname+"");
                    cmdissue = cmdissue.replace("value", ""+cdepth+"");
                    System.out.println(cmdissue);
                    cmdissue = null;
                }

                if (e.getSource() == txtchlname){chlname = txtchlname.getText(); chlname=null;}

                if (e.getSource() == txtchs)
                {   
                    chlstatus = txtchs.getText();
                    cmdissue = "chln is  chls";
                    cmdissue = cmdissue.replace("chln", ""+chlname+"");
                    cmdissue = cmdissue.replace("chls", ""+chlstatus+"");
                    System.out.println(cmdissue);
                }                   
            }
        }
```

I'm getting the expected outcome for the code:
[Running for first time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2imXz.png)

Say I close this object choice panel and open a new instance, irrespective of which choice I make the command runs twice:
[Running for the second time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9u6H.png)

The iteration repeats. Say I make a choice for the fourth or fifth time, the command runs 4/5 times.

I understood the fact that the somehow it is initializing the objects for the number of times I run it, and it needs to be reset after I close the panel. But I'm not sure how/where to get this done.

Apologies for the lengthy code posted, since I wanted to be sure that people can point the mistake that has been committed.

Comment: I agree, will improvise on the variable naming part. Meanwhile could you remove the last two variable names you have posted in the comment... 
I removed them from my code too. Since its sensitive info

Comment: Couldn't edit my comment anymore, so I deleted it.

Comment: @jesper much obliged

Comment: I have not checked the code but probably the action listener is being added each time to the same component when opened. This results in it being registered multiple time and consequently being called more than once...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
GridBagConstraints gbc_QMGR1 = new GridBagConstraints();
gbc_QMGR1.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
gbc_QMGR1.gridx = 1;
gbc_QMGR1.gridy = 1;
p.add(QMGR1, gbc_QMGR1);                
QMGR1.addActionListener(this);


GridBagConstraints gbc_QMGR1 = new GridBagConstraints();
gbc_QMGR1.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
gbc_QMGR1.gridx = 1;
gbc_QMGR1.gridy = 2;
p.add(QMGR1, gbc_QMGR1);        
QMGR1.addActionListener(this);
```

Looks like you are trying to add the same component to the panel twice in two different grid locations. You can't do this.

You need to:

1. create two different component, or
2. get rid of one of the components.

Edit:

```
        JButton QMGR1 = new JButton("QMGR1");
        JButton QMGR2 = new JButton("QMGR2");
```

You create the buttons as instance variables.

But then in the `makeQAPanel()` method you add the actionListener to the button.

```
QMGR1.addActionListener(this);

...

QMGR2.addActionListener(this);
```

So every time you invoke that method the actionListener gets added again.

The actionListener should be added in the constructor of you class so it is only added once.

Comment: Sorry that would be a typo in this post. Original src code has distinct values for this. I'll edit it here

Comment: I'm trying to work on your input:
"The actionListener should be added in the constructor or you class so it is only added once."
But getting confused where to add the actionListener, would you point to me where in the code this can be done to get the outcome?

Answer (score 0):

@jesper,

someone explained to me the constructor part of it:

package testbox;

```
    import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
    import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
    import java.awt.GridLayout;
    import java.awt.Insets;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

    import javax.swing.JButton;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JLabel;
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;
    import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
    import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
    import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
    import javax.swing.JTextArea;
    import javax.swing.JTextField;
    import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    public class MainFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener
    {   
        JLabel lblqname = new JLabel("Please enter the queue name");    
        JTextField txtqname = new JTextField(25);                       
        JLabel lblqcur = new JLabel("where curdeth greater than");      
        JTextField txtqcurdfil = new JTextField(5);                     

        JLabel lblchlname = new JLabel("Please enter the Channel name");
        JTextField txtchlname = new JTextField(30);     
        JLabel lblchs = new JLabel("where status is: ");
        JTextField txtchs = new JTextField(8);      

        public String ID;
        public String pwdValue;

        public String qname;    
        public int cdepth;

        public String chlname;
        public String chlstatus;

        public String cmdissue;

        JTextArea out = new JTextArea();

        JButton QMGR1 = new JButton("QMGR1");
        JButton QMGR2 = new JButton("QMGR2");


        public MainFrame()
        {   
            QMGR1.addActionListener(this);
            QMGR2.addActionListener(this);
            txtqname.addActionListener(this);
            txtqcurdfil.addActionListener(this);
            txtchlname.addActionListener(this);
            txtchs.addActionListener(this);


            JLabel jUserName = new JLabel("ID");
            JTextField userName = new JTextField();
            JLabel jPassword = new JLabel("Password");
            JTextField password = new JPasswordField();
            Object[] ob = {jUserName, userName, jPassword, password};
            int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, ob, "Please input password for Login", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);

            if (result == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) 
            {
                ID = userName.getText(); 
                pwdValue = password.getText(); 

            final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Environment Choice");
            frame.setSize(500, 400);
            frame.setVisible(true);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));
            JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane(JTabbedPane.TOP);

            tabbedPane.addTab("QAQmgrList", makeQAPanel());

            frame.getContentPane().add(tabbedPane);
            }

        }

        public JPanel makeQAPanel() 
        {
            JPanel p = new JPanel();
            p.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

            GridBagConstraints gbc_QMGR1 = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc_QMGR1.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
            gbc_QMGR1.gridx = 1;
            gbc_QMGR1.gridy = 1;
            p.add(QMGR1, gbc_QMGR1);                


            GridBagConstraints gbc_QMGR2 = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc_QMGR2.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
            gbc_QMGR2.gridx = 1;
            gbc_QMGR2.gridy = 2;
            p.add(QMGR2, gbc_QMGR2);        


            return p;
        }

        public void createSubframe()
        {   
            final JFrame subframe = new JFrame("Object Choice");
            subframe.setSize(1000, 500);        
            subframe.getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));
            out.setText(null);      
            out.setLineWrap(true);
            out.setCaretPosition(out.getDocument().getLength());
            out.setEditable (false);
            JScrollPane jp = new  JScrollPane(out);
            jp.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
            jp.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);

            JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane(JTabbedPane.TOP);

            JPanel queue = new JPanel();

            queue.add(lblqname);
            txtqname.setText(null);
            queue.add(txtqname);        
            queue.add(lblqcur);
            txtqcurdfil.setText(null);
            queue.add(txtqcurdfil);     


            JPanel chl = new JPanel();

            chl.add(lblchlname);
            txtchlname.setText(null);
            chl.add(txtchlname);
            chl.add(lblchs);
            txtchs.setText(null);
            chl.add(txtchs);



            tabbedPane.addTab("Queues", queue);
            tabbedPane.addTab("Channels", chl);     
            subframe.getContentPane().add(tabbedPane);
            subframe.getContentPane().add(jp);
            tabbedPane.setVisible(true);
            subframe.setVisible(true);      
        }   

        public static void main(String[] args) 
        {SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){ public void run() { @SuppressWarnings("unused") MainFrame m = new MainFrame();}});}

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
        {               
            if (e.getSource() == QMGR1|| e.getSource() == QMGR2) 
            {createSubframe();}     

            if (e.getSource() == txtqname){qname = txtqname.getText();}

            if (e.getSource() == txtqcurdfil)
            {   
                cdepth = Integer.parseInt(txtqcurdfil.getText());       
                cmdissue = "qn has value messages";
                cmdissue = cmdissue.replace("qn", ""+qname+"");
                cmdissue = cmdissue.replace("value", ""+cdepth+"");
                System.out.println(cmdissue);
                cmdissue = null;
            }

            if (e.getSource() == txtchlname){chlname = txtchlname.getText(); chlname=null;}

            if (e.getSource() == txtchs)
            {   
                chlstatus = txtchs.getText();
                cmdissue = "chln is  chls";
                cmdissue = cmdissue.replace("chln", ""+chlname+"");
                cmdissue = cmdissue.replace("chls", ""+chlstatus+"");
                System.out.println(cmdissue);
            }                   
        }
    }
```

Worked like a charm.. THanks for pointing it out